# Access to Scapy's inner protocol layers

Tags: python, networking, tcp, scapy

I'm writing my first program in Python.
I'm using a third-party kit for interacting with network packets (Scapy).

When I use this method:

```
p=sr1(IP(dst="google.com")/TCP())
```

the result is:

```
<IP  version=4L ihl=5L tos=0x0 len=44 id=18972 flags= frag=0L ttl=44
proto=tcp chksum=0x25bd src=173.194.39.134 dst=192.168.137.2
options=[] |<TCP  sport=www dport=ftp_data seq=1295300429 ack=1
dataofs=6L reserved=0L flags=SA window=14300 chksum=0x3c7e urgptr=0
options=[('MSS', 1430)] |<Padding  load='\x00\x00' |>>>
```

I can access to `chksum` of `IP` simply by `p.chksum`, but how can I access to `chksum` of `TCP`?

Comment: I don't know Scapy, but it's often useful to use `help` in the interactive interpreter when you don't know how to use a object.

Comment: What does `dir(sr1(IP(dst="google.com")/TCP()))` give you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general guideline, you should use

```
>>> p[TCP].chksum
```

However this only works for received packets because the checksum is calculated on transmit.  You can retrieve the checksum for an untransmitted packet with the show2() method.

Comment: Thanks, It works. And the another solution is `p.getlayer(TCP).chksum`

Comment: @masoud Thanks, this works fine in the Scapy interactive shell but within a python file I get a syntax error. To fix the error simply wrap/enclose the argument to getlayer() with double quotation. `p.getlayer("TCP").chksum`